# How to monitor disk space/file system usage of ecs cluster using fargate

Tags: docker, storage, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have created 2 tasks using Fargate and one ECS cluster which is using these 2 tasks in 2 different services. So in short one cluster: 2 services and each services are linked to their own tasks which linked to ECR repo. As per AWS ECS Fargate  task storage concept each task got 10gb of docker layer storage with additional 4gb volume mounts. So i would like to monitor the file system storage consumed by containers. I was thinking if anyone can point me how can i attach another docker sidecar to a task which will monitor the consumption of storage by the container created by that task and send it to cloud watch? Each task definition doesn’t have any mount points. Even if task restarts and creates new instances this should apply but i dont want to persist the data even if it restarted.

Comment: I can't find any officially supported way to achieve this at present. I suppose you could attempt to install the CloudWatch Agent inside the Task and have that send disk space usage metrics to CloudWatch? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance.html

Comment: Container Insights has StorageWriteBytes but it is in Bytes per second, not total. If you are concerned with data limits and monitoring it, you could attached EBS volumes or use EFS as the scratch space. Then use cloud watch to monitor those. If you don't care about retaining the data, why not just restart the task? What process are you trying to monitor in these tasks? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-reference-performance-logs-ECS.html

Comment: @strongjz, thanks. Fargate does not support EBS or EFS volumes. The question is not about retaining data, but giving an alarm when a Task may be about to fail if it is running out of storage space.

Comment: @Rich currently I'm using custom monitoring via cloudwatch agent to monitor the diskspace. At the same time, I think side car is nice concept to have which sits perfectly along side of your container not only monitoring/alarming disk space but also a lot other feature. and sidecar concept exists for EC2 but I haven't seen any sidecar concept on Fargate for AWSVPC network mode. if you have something, I would like to explore more.

Comment: @Rich also you are right for strongjz comment. Í'm interested in alarm not retaining in data.

Comment: @Rich Fargate does support EFS volumes. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-support-amazon-efs-filesystems-generally-available/

Comment: @change198 what provides the storage for the container? both layer storage and volume mounts

Answer (score 0):

I deployed side car that can source required custom data and push to CloudWatch as custom metric using AWS CLI.

https://github.com/saiteja313/amazon-cloudwatch-eks-fargate-metrics/blob/master/cloudwatch-fargate-metrics/cw-put-pod-metrics.sh#L23

Considering your use case, you can run a command like `du -h ./ | grep [0-9]G` as part of the script and push value to CloudWatch, create alarm if storage goes beyond certain threshold like 7 GB.