# Monitor disk usage of ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an ECS cluster and facing an issue that sometimes one or two EC2 instances ran out of disk which I have to manually cleanup or terminate.

I'd like to have a dashboard or graph to show the disk usage, preferably P90 to trace the worst cases.

Is there a buildin metrics from AWS, or it has to be a customized solution? I use Terraform if that's related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59888358

Comment: Maybe. I do not use Fargate tho.

Comment: I believe the CloudWatch agent should be pre-installed on the EC2 instances. The CloudWatch agent on the instance can report disk volume usage to CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html Then it is just a matter of creating a metric in CloudWatch to alarm when usage is high.

Comment: Under a cluster it is a bit awkward, e.g. the instance IDs are not readily available. Even with the instance IDs, another awkward example is that the metrics/alarm has to be cleaned up / deleted after an instance dies.

Answer (score 2):

[CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) can do this for you. Here's an example Terraform script that accomplishes this derived from this very helpful [blog article](https://jazz-twk.medium.com/cloudwatch-agent-on-ec2-with-terraform-8cf58e8736de).

main.tf

```
# Implementation based on https://jazz-twk.medium.com/cloudwatch-agent-on-ec2-with-terraform-8cf58e8736de

locals {
  role_policy_arns = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2RoleforSSM",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
  ]
  userdata = templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.tpl", {
    ssm_cloudwatch_config = aws_ssm_parameter.cloudwatch_agent.name
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cloudwatch_agent" {
  count = length(local.role_policy_arns)

  role       = var.instance_profile_role_name
  policy_arn = element(local.role_policy_arns, count.index)
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "cloudwatch_agent" {
  name = "${var.name}-EC2-Inline-Policy"
  role = var.instance_profile_role_id
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : [
            "ssm:GetParameter"
          ],
          "Resource" : "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "cloudwatch_agent" {
  description = "Cloudwatch agent config"
  name        = "/${var.service}/cloudwatch_agent_config.json"
  tags        = var.tags
  type        = "String"

  value = templatefile("${path.module}/config.tpl", {
    namespace               = "${var.service}/CWAgent"
  })
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name."
}

variable "tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "The tags."
}

variable "service" {
  type        = string
  description = "The service name."
}

variable "instance_profile_role_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The instance profile role ID."
}

variable "instance_profile_role_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The instance profile role name."
}
```

userdata.tpl

```
# Configure Cloudwatch agent
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
rpm -U ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm

# Use cloudwatch config from SSM
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl \
-a fetch-config \
-m ec2 \
-c ssm:${ssm_cloudwatch_config} -s
```

config.tpl

```
{
    "agent": {
      "metrics_collection_interval": 60
    },
    "metrics": {
      "namespace": "${namespace}",
      "metrics_collected": {
          "mem": {
            "measurement": [
              "used_percent",
              "total"
            ]
          }
      },
      "append_dimensions": {
          "InstanceId": "$${aws:InstanceId}",
          "AutoScalingGroupName": "$${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
      },
      "aggregation_dimensions": [["InstanceId"], ["AutoScalingGroupName"]]
    }
}
```

Note: My configuration is for retrieving memory usage (something I was surprised to find isn't available by default on EC2 instances) but it's easy to modify it for whatever metrics you are interested in as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html) (search for `disk` to see the disk metrics).

You will need to insert `local.userdata` into your EC2 instance launch user data for the CloudWatch agent to be properly installed/configured.